# Location permission alert on iPhone with PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova, core-location

How do you change the string on the alert saying:

> (Appname/whatever it is) would like to use your current location

Of course, I only want to change the appname part. Because when you use the PhoneGap framework, the string is *very* ugly, something like this:

> /var/mobile/Applications/157EB70D-4AA7-826E-690F0CBE0F/appname.app/www/index.html

Someone having an idea?

Answer (score 94):

You need to do the geolocation after the device is ready.  The following Jquery code, for example, will geolocate without that nasty alert:

```
$(function(){
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
})

function onDeviceReady() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);     
}

function onSuccess(position) {
  // your callback here 
}

function onError(error) { 
  // your callback here
}
```

Comment: excellent answer, solved my problem. why the right answer is not on the top?

Comment: Yes! I agree, this should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks, Pius; this solved my problem.

Comment: I've added this code. But the result for me is the 2 alerts will appear on the first run from xcode on the simulator. then on the 2nd run, only the 2nd alert appears. on the 3rd run, the alerts do not appear anymore. that's kinda weird.

Comment: this solution doesn't work for me, the second alert still appear. none of these solutions helps me!

Comment: Waiting for the device works well for me as well. However, it only works for devices. If you use Cordova with Ionic, and use this approach, location services will not work in the browser. I added a switch that checks if the app runs in a browser. If so, I run the navigator code instantly. If I'm on a device, I wait for the device to be ready.

Comment: Hello, How to Disable Location permission alert on iPhone with Cordova.

Comment: This is not even the answer, the question is to change the content of the alert, not remove it, and you will get it the first time you install the app anyways

Answer (score 17):

On phonegap 3.0 the answer by Pius Uzamere needs to be followed AND the plugin installed.

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
```

otherwise you will get the double permission request.

Comment: If using PhoneGap Build, don't forget to add that plugin to your config.xml file: <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />

Comment: when running `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation` it will install from the [apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) repo on GitHub - which is a mirror of the [apache.org repo](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git)

Answer (score 13):

I just followed the documentation and solved it.
Open the terminal and cd to your project and enter following command.
**$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git**

Also add this in your config.xml

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
```

It will solve this issue. :)

Source: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#The%20Command-line%0AInterface

Comment: That works for me, I have reinstalled the plugin: 
`cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.geolocation` then `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation` which add the previous `<feature name="Geolocation">` lines that were missing.

Answer (score 8):

Although this question is much older, I found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891339/fix-cordova-geolocation-ask-for-location-message/30742592) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302242/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-cordova/30742445).

For my resolution, I had to add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to the .plist file. However, I suppose since my geolocation plugin was out of date, I had to update it first. Then I had to remove/add the Cordova iOS platform. Finally, I added `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to the .plist file.

First, remove/add the geolocation plugin:

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.geolocation
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

Second, remove/add the iOS platform:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Last, add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to the .plist. Open `/platforms/ios/{project}/{project}-Info.plist` and add the following:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>[App Name] would like to access your location when running and displayed.</string>
```

See this [iOS Developer Library link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18) for detailed information regarding `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` versus `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` versus `NSLocationUsageDescription`.

Answer (score 7):

Finally fixed the issue.

IN the index.html just move your cordova.js up

       <script src="cordova.js"></script>

as the first js file to be included (especially make sure it is above maps include js). This will make sure that the prompt shows only once.

No other codejs or ondeviceready is needed.

Comment: I think this would fix a lot of issues in any phonegap/cordova project but not necessarily the cause for this issue

Comment: solved my problem - that was severely annoying. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

After looking for solution i've founded, just add a variable when you add the plugin location like this line

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message"
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me. My location request was already firing on deviceready. Adding the following to config.xml fixed the issue:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation" />
```

Comment: If you are using PhoneGap build you will need to add the plugin to your config.xml as you describe.

I needed to do this and make sure my calls were inside onDeviceReady

Comment: Where did you put that statement to? `config.xml`?

Comment: "Adding the following to config.xml fixed the issue" :)

Answer (score 2):

To solve the issue I have to run `cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git` which adds (automatically) to the config.xml the following:

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
     <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
```

To get things working I have to put also this lines into the config.xml:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice" />
        <plugin name="Logger" value="CDVLogger" />
        <plugin name="Compass" value="CDVLocation" />
        <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
        <plugin name="Debug Console" value="CDVDebugConsole" />
        <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
        <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
        <plugin name="Battery" value="CDVBattery" />
        <plugin name="Globalization" value="CDVGlobalization" />
    </plugins>
```

Hope it could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After making sure my `geolocation` request was called after the device was ready, making sure the geolocation plugin is correctly installed and configured, I was still receiving the unsightly popup.

I resolved it by moving and referencing my `cordova.js` file and `cordova_plugins.js` files into the root directory of my application (they were originally in a subfolder), so the path to `cordova.js` would be:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I feel this should be included in the documentation (maybe it is, but I haven't managed to find it)

Answer (score 1):

- Just by including "cordova.js" file in your html file where you are accessing this location will resolve this issue. NOTHING FANCY REQUIRED.

Comment: In my case the ugly message is not gone the first time you open your app.

Answer (score 0):

1) modify Location.m in PhoneGapLib project. replace all references of 
navigator.geolocation with navigator_geo

2) Copy phonegap.js to phonegap2.js and put in root of app. I have now 
learned that every time I build my application and load it onto device 
or simulator, the phonegap.js file is being regenerated. OK. Well I 
need to modify it so lets just use another one and deal with the 
hassles of upgrading in the future.

3) Modify the line (in phonegap2.js) that creates the constructor for 
the navigator.geolocation on 626 to be ... if (typeof navigator._geo 
== "undefined") navigator._geo = new Geolocation();

4) Now in your HTML whenever you want to use the PHONEGAP GPS stuff, 
you can reference it with navigator._geo.getCurrentPosition or similar 
5) Enjoy the ONE, and CLEAN, location alert permission without 
revealing to your users your intelligence to use PhoneGap and build an 
app with HTML/JS.

*** CAVEAT AND PLEASE HELP! ***

If I run the watchPosition function, I will get the first location 
update with all sorts of stats. There after, It will always report an 
error. I assume this sucks for this 30 second time of getting accurate 
GPS on these things?

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/8067c2037816a9ad

Answer (score 0):

I followed all the instructions and it still failed. In the end I played around with the PhoneGap demo and found the **final solution**:

1. Move all the js files and html files into the same folder (not even sub-folder). Congratulations! Problem solved, no permission alert any more : )
2. BTW, You'd better use a " setTimeout(function(){utility.getGeoData();},1000);"  I found "document.addEventListener("deviceready", utility.getGeoData(), false);" not work for me.

Hope that helps when you find no solution above : )

Good luck!

Comment: “document.addEventListener("deviceready",utility.getGeoData(),false)” is not working because you are executing getGeoData, which makes its return value become the second parameter to addEventListener instead of the function. Remove the brackets for it and it should work. Ad@m

Comment: I found that I needed to set a timout too.  Thanks Bingo!

Answer (score 0):

Since I was struggling for days now with the same problem and finally found the solution, I decided to share it with anyone who still was not able to fix it.

The solution is simple: The geolocation plugin was missing in the plugins directory within the www directory, even though I added the plugin via the phonegap command line interface AND the plugin files were in the /Plugins directory. So you only have to copy the missing files into /www/plugins and you are done. Just simple as that.

If anyone needs the missing files: http://d.pr/f/xqhq

btw: i am using cordova 3.2.0.

I hope this works for you as well!

Answer (score 0):

Phoengap/Cordova version 3.5 here.

Similar to Manuel's answer above but this time the plugin does not install in the platforms/ios/[appname]/Plugins folder.

The fix for me was to just manually create a new folder for the plugin in the ../platforms/ios/[appname]/Plugins folder > then rename it to org.apache.cordova.geolocation > then copy the .h and .m files of the plugin into it.

You can find the .m and .h files for the geoLocation plugin in the [root]/plugins/org.apache.cordova.geolocation/src/ios directory.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error (and a lot of others) after upgrading Cordova from 3.6 to 4.3.

I think there is some fails in the upgrade process and the only working solution for me was `cordova platform rm ios` then `cordova platform add ios`

/!\ You will lost all your ios project settings and you need to reupload splash and icons.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using Cordova/Ionic and have experienced the same problem. That's because of the code before device is ready.  I have simply wrapped the code with document.addEventListener on "deviceready". For example:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){
      ...your code here...
    });
});
```

Then the additional message does not appear.

Answer (score -1):

I'm late to the party here, but will answer the question for reference.
The answer is to use the geolocation functions found in phonegap.js which is included with Phonegap. You will be able to find such instructions on the Phonegap site at http://www.phonegap.com.

If you use `navigator.geolocation`, you are using the default Safari geolocation system. This happens as PhoneGap works by running your pages effectively in a Safari instance. If you include phonegap.js into your site, you can use a separate geolocation method exposed by PhoneGap's Objective-C code, which will present the behaviour seen in other apps where it asks for permission from [your app name].

Comment: Can you point to the exact location in phonegap.com where this is written?

Comment: @Tim Rogers Seems, you're wrong (at least three years after your answer). PhoneGap overrides this object and these methods, and when you're calling `navigator.geolocation`, you're actually calling PhoneGap API. [Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition) is link to proper document. PhoneGap then decides, whether it can user device-provided gelocation mechanism or should fall back to its own ("This API is based on the W3C Geolocation API Specification, and only executes on devices that don't already provide an implementation")

Answer (score -2):

"Move all the js files and html files into the same folder (not even sub-folder). Congratulations! Problem solved, no permission alert any more : )" Like Caleb says works for me, well only moving the cordova.js file to the root and adding the plugin to config.xml

Answer (score -3):

What is the Bundle display name of your project?

Try changing manually from the default value `${PRODUCT_NAME}` and see..

That Permission to use location alert picks your bundle display name only!!

Comment: It doesnt matter, I have set both "bundle display name" and "bundle name" properties manually! The one I havent set manually is "Executable file" which is ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}. But if I change that I cant compile, obviously..