# PhoneGap geolocation asks for permission twice on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, permissions, geolocation, cordova

My app uses navigator.geolocation provided by PhoneGap. When running the app on iPhone is asks for location permissions twice, i guess one for the app and one for safari, how do i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem, but this fixed it:
[Location permission alert on iPhone with PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673579/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-phonegap)

you have to rely on OnDeviceReady(), and it'll only call once.

Answer (score 1):

Call the geolocation initialisation in `onDeviceReady` Method and load this in body tag

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me somehow. It asks for permissions twice

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't disable the second alert, because it is coming from WebKit and not iOS. 
However, I suggest you [write a bug on the WebKit Bugzilla](http://bugs.webkit.org) and ask them to disable the second alert when PhoneGap is being used in an app if you believe two confirmation messages will be confusing to the user.

Ad@m

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution, at least did it work for me: some files of the geolocation plugin were missing! You can find my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20751284/3130771).