# Can't use PhoneGap's geolocaiton API; Safari always used instead. Ugly geolocation prompt appears

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation, extjs

I have a Sencha app which performs geolocation, and provides a list of nearby venues based on the results.

I am using PhoneGap:Build (the automated service); this point might be of importance. I am not dealing with the PhoneGap files at all - I am letting PhoneGap:Build automatically create the apps for all platforms. So far it has been spectacular.

The problem: I understand that attempting to geolocate before 'deviceready' is triggered may result in a geolocation call using the Safari geolocation instead of the device geolocation. The side-effect I am experiencing is this terrible message prompt:

```
'/var/mobile/Applications/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX/AppName.app/www/index.html would like to use your current location'
```

Now, this is *still* happening after I introduce even a 10 second delay - long enough to ensure that PhoneGap has long since been loaded. This is where I am confused. This only happens in iOS; Android build seems fine.

Why am I getting this message? I have the following line in my config.xml:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```

..Which I figured was sufficient to open up the PhoneGap geolocation API, thus avoiding this horrible message.

I should also note that I get *double* prompted; the first time geolocation is performed, I get this:

```
'App Name would like to use your location'
```

Which is then followed by a second message - the ugly one I outlined above.

Why are two prompts being displayed back-to-back? Why not just the first one? I've spent days on this.. completely out of ideas. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This same issue is addressed
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673579/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-phonegap).

Basically they again take you
[here](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/8067c2037816a9ad?pli=1).

which explains a fairly in depth process but at least it works.

Comment: Currently, there is much easier solution posted to that question -- you have to make sure, you're calling geolocation API **after device is ready**, to see application name, not URL, requesting for location permission -- see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5018461/1469208) for more details.