# Phonegap/Cordova Geolocation IPhone

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation, alert

I have some issues with a phonegap application using the geolocation of the user. Everytime the page is opened in the app, we get the following message[image: Error Message on iOS]

It would be nice, to prevent the app of showing this hint.

We use Cordova 1.9, PhoneGap Build and have set the right in the config.xml to access the position:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```

We cannot make deep changes in the objectiv-c code like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673579/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-phonegap) because we use PhoneGap Build!

My code looks like the following...

```
function onDeviceReady() {

    // get position
    if (watchId == null) {
        killWatcher();
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateUserPosition, log, {
                enableHighAccuracy: false
            });
            watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(updateUserPosition, onGPSError, {
                frequency : 5000,
                maximumAge : 30000,
                enableHighAccuracy : true
            });
            localStorage.setItem("watchID", watchId);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

The function listens on the ondeviceready event.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem here was that Cordova.js was not included on all pages.