# android geolocation permission promt not coming - phoonegap application

Tags: cordova

I am building an HTML5 app where in I am testing the geolocation feature.
I am using the below code to access the geolocation of user.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
    }
```

When I run app with this code on android using phonegap, I don't see the permission prompt to allow or deny the geolcation of user.

However, on desktop browser the prompt displays.

I am directly loading my web page as in below code in my main activity file. I am not using the webview object.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Code/Test.html");
}
```

The permissions are given properly in the manifest file and I am getting the geolocation of user but the permissions prompt doesnt display in android.

Comment: do you add permission in your app/AndroidManifest.xml ?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a reference to confirm my answer but I believe this is the intended behavior. When you load the application in a web browser you haven't explicitly given permission to the app to know your location. Thus you're prompted to give the app access to that info. In a mobile app you give that permission when you install the app. That's why (at least in Android) you are shown a list of permissions that application wants when you install it. Then when you run the app you've already said it can have access to your location.

Comment: Exactly. You give it permission the moment you install the application.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you're calling geolocation API after device is ready -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5018461/1469208) for more details.