# Double prompt for geolocation in Trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io

Essentially, I am having this issue:

[How to prevent double prompt for geolocation in Phonegap app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857165/how-to-prevent-double-prompt-for-geolocation-in-phonegap-app)

But inside of Trigger.io instead of Phonegap.

To make things more interesting, I am not calling navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition directly - I am creating a geolocation watcher using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition.

There does not appear to be a substitute for this function in Trigger's API:

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/geolocation.html

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed we unfortunately don't have a native version of the `watchPosition` function, we do provide a `getCurrentPosition` however which won't prompt the user. Until we support `watchPosition` you might be best doing `getCurrentPosition` in a `setInterval` to periodically monitor a users position.