# Location permission alert shows up twice using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, geolocation, phonegap-build

I've been struggling with this for the past two days.  I have looked at various responses but none have solved my problem.  I am using Phonegap Build to publish an iPhone app.  One on of the features is to get the user's current location.  Before the map loads I get two alerts, the first one is a normal alert asking me if I want to grant my current location.  However the second alert show a directory path where the file is located also asking if I want to grant the app permission to my location (see image below)  I tried the following suggested solution here [Location permission alert on iPhone with PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673579/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-phonegap)  without any luck.

This is what I have in my config.xml file

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="npm"/>

<allow-intent href="geo:*" />

<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>

<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>

<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="false">
   <array>
      <string>needs your location</string>
   </array>
</gap:config-file>
```

I call the init function from the body tag

```
     function init(){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
     }
     function onDeviceReady(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);    
     }
```

[image]
I also tried these solutions but none work

[How to prevent double prompt for geolocation in Phonegap app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857165/how-to-prevent-double-prompt-for-geolocation-in-phonegap-app)

[Location permission alert on iPhone with Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302242/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-cordova/30742445#30742445)

What could I be doing wrong?  Are there any examples or tutorials that anyone can recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, I added the following lines and the second alert no longer shows up

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which following lines was you added ?

Answer (score 1):

put you geolocation code inside platform.ready()

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp.coords.latitude);
      console.log(resp.coords.longitude);

})
```