# Cannot geolocate with googlemaps in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3

I try to geolocate on a google map in Phonegap using jquery.
I try the following code, but it does not work. I get the alert("1") but not the alert("2") :

```
alert("1");
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {
                  alert("2");
                  if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                  var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                  $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': clientPosition});
                  $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition, 'bounds': true});
                  $('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 'Circle', {
                                        'strokeWeight': 0,
                                        'fillColor': "#008595",
                                        'fillOpacity': 0.25,
                                        'center': clientPosition,
                                        'radius': 15,
                                        'clickable': false
                                        });
                  }
            });
```

An idea ? Please :)

These are my .js files :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.extensions.js"></script>
```

map_canvas refers to this div in my html :
id="map_canvas" style="width:250px;height:250px"

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Why you're using `.gmap` function, to get current location, instead of  using `navigator.geolocation` object? Also, make sure, you're calling geolocation API after device is ready -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5018461/1469208) for more details.

Comment: Thks. This is finally what I did