# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition Phonegap - Stop alerts

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

This question has been asked many times, but each answer is the same, yet it doesn't work for me...

When I call navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition I get two alert boxes. One native, and the other from the webview (Safari). The general answer is to place the call in the Deviceready call. I am placing it in that listener, yet i still receive two alerts. (the second is very ugly!).

Any ideas on how to fix this??

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
}
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: What do the alerts say that you are getting?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

I am getting an alert to allow the location for the app. which is normal for apps, but i then get an allow location for the index.html once the app fully loads. This is the one that needs removing...

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Cordova/PhoneGap 3.0 or greater, make sure you have added the **Geolocation plugin** to your app project, otherwise you'll get the double alert.

If using Cordova, cd into your project directory, then enter the following command in the command line:

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation`

If using PhoneGap, you can try this command instead:

`phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation`

Thanks to Robert Verge at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839828

Comment: Hi, thanks for the time, but i get this error, after lots of "skipping existing file": 
{ name: 'SyntaxError',
  message: 'Expected "/*", "=" or [A-Za-z0-9_] but "." found.',
  line: 458,
  column: 11 }

Comment: Just updated my original answer with revised plugin URLs that use a newer, more simpler format (though the old ones should still work too).

Comment: But if you're still having troubles, I'd suggest upgrading to Cordova 3.1 (if you haven't already) and then try starting afresh with a brand new Cordova project.  I think I remember having a similar problem once, and starting with a clean project fixed it.  Just keep a copy of your existing project, create the new one, then copy back in your www folder, app icons, splashscreens and any settings you have previously changed in Xcode.  Here's a Gist https://gist.github.com/wicketyjarjar/7042737 detailing the steps I commonly use to start a new Cordova project.

Comment: Thanks for the update, i still get the same errors though... i will try a 3.1 update. see what happens.

Comment: Still no joy, i have now given up on PhoneGap, it seems to lead me into problems all over the app. I am now going to try and make this as a native iOS app...

Comment: Sorry to hear it's still not working for you. When everything is running correctly, Cordova is really good. Version 3.2.0 fixes a lot of issues and has just been released. It might be worth another try. Just run `sudo npm install -g cordova` from the command line to get the latest version. Otherwise, best of luck with the native development. I tried it unsuccessfully a few times before settling on Cordova. The ability to use the same code for iOS and Android is a big benefit.