# Cordova multiple location request

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I'm having a multiple location requests with Cordova. After it has already requested the use of my location for the app, it asks this [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the Geolocation plugin and also check that you are doing Geolocation after "deviceready", all mentioned here [Location permission alert on iPhone with PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673579/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-phonegap#answer-5018461)