# Fix Cordova Geolocation Ask for Location Message

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, geolocation, message

Does anyone have experience using cordova, html and know how to fix this geolocation message issue for iOS? I just want the message to say the app name followed by the line, "would like to use your current location."

Current Geolocation Message:

> ///Users/kklsndksjladn/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FAF7EE4C-40BA-430A-80D5-5C84B07D970D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DAE305B6-C6DD-438B-B4D7-9B183A8B2D97/HelpME.app/www/index.html

I've tried various solutions from stack overflow and other websites.  I implemented the  `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);` code, included my cordova.js file in every html page, made sure `<script> src=cordova.js</script>` appears first in my index.html page, included the geolocation tag in my config.xml file and tried playing around with my plist.  Someone please help!!!!

-Thanks

Comment: did you install the geolocation plugin?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810880/cordova-ios-location-message/40963681#40963681).

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the answer from [DaveAlden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777265/davealden), I had to remove the old version of the geolocation plugin and add the new one. Then I had to remove/add the Cordova iOS platform. Only then could I add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to the .plist file with success.

First, remove/add the geolocation plugin:

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.geolocation
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

Second, remove/add the iOS platform:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Last, add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to the .plist. Open `/platforms/ios/{project}/{project}-Info.plist` and add the following:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>[App Name] would like to access your location when running and displayed.</string>
```

See this [iOS Developer Library link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18) for detailed information regarding `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` versus `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` versus `NSLocationUsageDescription`.

[Location permission alert on iPhone with Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302242/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-cordova/30742445#30742445) is a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

To customise the iOS location permission request message, you need to add a property to your project's .plist.

If your app requests permission to use location in the background, you want the following key (set the string value to anything you like):

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>My app requires constant access to your location, even when the screen is off.</string>
```

If your app only uses location while in the foreground, then add the following key:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>My app requires access to your location when the screen is on and the app is displayed.</string>
```

Comment: It works in iOS 8 (I'm using it my own [Cordova-powered geolocation app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iwalk-north-cornwall/id739048330?ls=1&mt=8)). If you're testing with an older version of iOS, you need to use `NSLocationUsageDescription` - [see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18)