# Location permission alert on iPhone with PhoneGap and ionic

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

This is a follow up from:
[Location permission alert on iPhone with PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673579/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-phonegap)

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AQjG.jpg

None of the answers there worked and I am still getting the 
    "/private/var ... would like to use your location" message. 
 I have $cordovaGeolocation in a factory

```
.factory('$cordovaGeolocation', ['$q', 'geo', function ($q) {

return {
    getCurrentPosition: function (options) {
        var q = $q.defer();

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (result) {
            q.resolve(result);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(q.resolve(result)));
        }, function (err) {
            q.reject(err);
        }, options);

        return q.promise;
    },

    watchPosition: function (options) {
        var q = $q.defer();

        var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (result) {
            q.notify(result);
        }, function (err) {
            q.reject(err);
        }, options);

        q.promise.cancel = function () {
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
        };

        q.promise.clearWatch = function (id) {
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id || watchID);
        };

        q.promise.watchID = watchID;

        return q.promise;
    },

    clearWatch: function (watchID) {
        return navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
    }
};
}])
```

and call it in a resolve in my .state

```
resolve : {
  initialGeo: function ($cordovaGeolocation) {
    var posOptions = {timeout: 1000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
    return $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions);
  }
}
```

I cannot get rid of this awful message. I'm using the latest ionic and cordova versions with the plain 'ol phonegap geolocation plugin.

What I've tried:
- Changes to the config.xml

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
<plugins>
    <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice" />
    <plugin name="Logger" value="CDVLogger" />
    <plugin name="Compass" value="CDVLocation" />
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
    <plugin name="Debug Console" value="CDVDebugConsole" />
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    <plugin name="Battery" value="CDVBattery" />
    <plugin name="Globalization" value="CDVGlobalization" />
</plugins>
```

- Ripping out the factory and just doing

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onsuccess, onerror, params);
  }, false);
- Moving cordova.js to the first script to be loaded.
- Move all js files to root.

The normal permission alert shows once. The ugly one shows 2-3 times and then doesn't show again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If you're asking for geolocation immediately, adding a delay to the route fixed it for me.

```
resolve : {
  waitOnMe: function ( $timeout) {
  return  $timeout(function () { }, 100);
  }
}
```