# How to show a custom message in the confirm box of location permission on iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova

The confirm box for HTML5 geolocation permission on the Phonegap application for iOS is like:
[image]

How can I set a more user-friendly message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673579/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-phonegap