# ionic app - how to avoid location permission dialog on ios device

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic v1 app. Whenever I open the app in ios.. I get the following screen. is there any way to avoid it? it looks bad - and doesn't happen when i build the same code for android.

Is there any code that is creating this??

[image]

Comment: note - i'm happy with the usual permissions - but not this dialog which shows the whole URL if you know what i mean.

Comment: in info.plist, It will mentioned in **USAGE DESCRIPTION for location access**. thats why it is displaying like this.

Comment: do u want to change that path data to  your app name or totally you don't want to show this??

Comment: just not show it.

Comment: i'm using ionic package (cloud build) so i can't change the info.plist file

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673579/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-phonegap